# Invalid Arguments Error Using PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER In GNU MCU Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse

I am using GNU MCU Eclipse 4.7.2-202001271244 with GCC Linaro 7.5.0 (arm-linux-gnueabihf).  Both are the latest versions as of now

I set up a simple project that uses pthreads and when I try to use PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER I get an error in Eclipse even though g++ compiles it without error.  The error from Eclipse is:

> Invalid arguments ' Candidates are:  ()  (const
>   {C:\Download\gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-i686-mingw32_arm-linux-gnueabihf\arm-linux-gnueabihf\libc\usr\include\bits\pthreadtypes.h:1809}
>   &) '

Looking at pthreadtypes.h, line 1809 is not even a valid line number

My test code is very simple:

```
#include <pthread.h>

int main(const int argc, const char* const argv[])
{
    pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);

    return 0;
}
```

I am pretty confident my project is set up correctly because I can take the g++ generated executable and run it successfully on my ARM processor

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions on resolving this issue?  Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.  I have tried searching for information with no luck

Comment: This error looks like an error from gcc, not from eclipse. Where does this error show up?

Comment: @user7860670 This error shows up in the Eclipse problems view.  The actual g++ build run to completion without any errors displayed in the console view